# Facebook prepare information for facebook friends

Tags: java, facebook, rest, facebook-graph-api

Dears,
I've checked Facebook's documentation and read multiple posts regarding this topic. It seems we are now only able to retrieve user's friends which are also using the application.

An alternative is to send a Dialog box to "invite" them or share links.

Each user of my web platform has its own website and can give access to his website to any user. I can send invitation links using a GUID to his facebook friends, but I would like to list his friends, let him choose the ones he wants to invite and assign them a unique code and some other information before sending them the invitation link.

Is this something feasible with the latest Facebook api ?

Comment: check out the invitable_friends endpoint and its limitations in the docs

Answer (score 0):

The "invitable_friends" endpoint is only for "games" as mentionned in the documentation. I had to use the "taggable_friends" endpoint.
I'm using spring-social plugin and I ended up with something like this :

```
        Facebook facebook = new FacebookTemplate(getUserFromSecurityContext().getFacebookAccessToken());
        String guid = (String) session.getAttribute(FRIENDS_NEXT_PAGE);
        PagedList<UserTaggableFriend> friends;
        if (null != guid) {
            friends = facebook.fetchConnections("me",
                    "taggable_friends?after=" + guid, UserTaggableFriend.class,
                    "id", "name", "picture", "first_name", "last_name", "middle_name");
        } else {
            friends = facebook.friendOperations().getTaggableFriends();
        }
```

where 'guid' is a link to the next or previous page.